# How to add a new address (shipping or billing or another) via Magento 2 REST API?

Tags: magento2, customer, api, rest-api, customer-address

There are API's available to fetch and delete address of a customer but not create a new one.

```
GET    /V1/customers/addresses/:addressId
GET    /V1/customers/me/billingAddress
GET    /V1/customers/:customerId/billingAddress
GET    /V1/customers/me/shippingAddress
GET    /V1/customers/:customerId/shippingAddress
DELETE /V1/addresses/:addressId
```

POST Api's are not available publicly?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I was having a similar problem and was digging into the AccountManagement class to find the proper payload. I noticed that the createAccount function checks if a customer ID exists and loads the stored data.

By performing a `POST /V1/customers/:id`, I was able to add another address with the following payload:

```
{ "customer":
    {
       "email":"testing2@testing.com",
       "firstname":"test",
       "lastname":"test",
       "websiteId": 0,
       "addresses": [
            {
                "id": 9,
                "firstname": "test",
                "lastname": "test",
                "company": "test technology",
                "street": [
                "Test Street 9",
                "Tiny House 9"
                ],
                "city": "City Nine",
                "region_id": 12,
                "region": "California",
                "postcode": "91790",
                "country_id": "US",
                "telephone": "1234567890"
            },
            {
                "firstname": "test",
                "lastname": "test",
                "company": "test technology",
                "street": [
                "Test Street 10",
                "Tiny House 10"
                ],
                "city": "City Ten",
                "region_id": 12,
                "region": "California",
                "postcode": "91790",
                "country_id": "US",
                "telephone": "1234567890"
            }
        ]
    }
```

By post method how did you do this actually when i am trying it is showing me error of missing route did you write webapi.xml code for this route.

**Another Way:**

add endp point app/code/YourCompany/Customer/etc/webapi.xml

```
<route url="/V1/addresses" method="POST">
        <service class="Magento\Customer\Api\AddressRepositoryInterface" method="save"/>
        <resources>
            <resource ref="Magento_Customer::manage"/>
        </resources>
    </route>
```

Body:

```
{
  "address": { 
    "customer_id": "363",
    "defaultShipping": true,
    "defaultBilling": true,
     "region": "Adabor - Dhaka",
    "country_id": "BD",
    "street": [  "304, Tejgaon IA" ],
    "postcode": "1208",
    "city": "Dhaka",
    "firstname": "Matin",
    "lastname": "Api Adrss",   
    "telephone": "01717676441",
    "countryId": "BD"
  }
}
```

If Update Existing address add addressID on body preload:

```
"id": 323,
"customer_id": "363",
```

Post: http://yourstore.com/rest/V1/addresses [admin integration token]

[get CustomerID http://yourstore.com/rest/V1/customers/me getMethod customer token]

Comment: In Magento 2.3, I tried PUT and it works like a charm!

Comment: How do we know the address id while updating customer.

Answer (score 6):

It should be possible to add/update customer addresses using customer repository  API:

```
PUT /V1/customers/:id (for admin)
PUT /V1/customers/me (for customer)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Magento 2.2, PUT and POST both do not work for adding a new address to an existing account. I get the following error:

"A customer with the same email already exists in an associated website"

Is adding an address to an existing Magento customer only supported in version 2.3 and later?

Comment: UPDATE: I was able to get the endpoint "PUT /V1/customers/:id" to work but an additional field was needed in the "customer" object. After adding an "id" field (Magento customer ID), I am able to add addresses to an already existing customer account.

Answer (score 0):

> /V1/customers/me

This endpoint is available only for customer and with ajax.

Comment: When I said customer, I mean with customer bearer token (/integration/customer/token)

Answer (score 0):

There is an `AddressRespository` API available in the core. We can use this API to save the address without using the Customer Entity.

File: vendor/magento/module-customer/Api/AddressRepositoryInterface.php
Method: save()

As this is not linked with any endpoint, we may have to create a custom REST endpoint and pass the `Address` object as POST request.

POST Body would look like this:

```
{
    "address": {
        "customer_id": 24,
        "firstname": "Harish",
        "lastname": "ST",
        "telephone": "",
        "region_id": 550,
        "country_id": "IN",
        "street": [
            "My Street Address"
        ],
        "postcode": "000000",
        "city": "City",
        "default_shipping": true,
        "default_billing": true
    }
}
```

I used this to create new addressed for my Mobile application.